Robotframework-Selenium Library IDLE unless interacting with page somehow
So I have only come across two other posts regarding this issue. However, they are a little too complex for me in terms of what I am doing. Plus, I do not believe they have answers that permanently fix.
So I'm writing an automation script, and it works as intended until I get to a certain part of the script. I have tried used Reload Page, Mouse Over, etc to simulate my cursor moving so it continues however nothing is working.
The problem is once I get to that part of the script, it will stop indefinitely until I somehow am interacting with the page. I can move the cursor and it'll slowly continue, or I can scroll up and down and that very much speeds up the process, however it is kind of spotty and makes the script stop if something is even slightly out of place. Any suggestions on what to do or how to fix it?
I tried using Reload Page, Mouse Over, continuous mouse overs to other part. Even tried looking for a simulate cursor, however that does not exist in robot framework.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
